What is the default PowerShell console font on Windows 10 & 11?
I am fairly new to PowerShell.
The font Consolas size 16 has been the default in the PowerShell console, on the machine on which I started learning PowerShell, which runs Windows 11 22H2 (22621.674).
I recently had to use PowerShell on another machine and the default font was Lucida Console, however in the same size 16. That machine runs Windows 10 22H2 (19045.5131) and was freshly re-imaged, however not by me (company laptop).
My personal machine is on W10 22H2 and has Consolas, however in size 14, as the default.
What font and size is set by default for PowerShell console on fresh installs of Windows ?

The default font on Windows 10 and Windows 11 can be different, I can confirm, the font you describe is the default font on Windows 11

PowerShell and PowerShell ISE are two different things, and i did launch PowerShell not Windows Terminal.

The default behaviour on my version of Windows 11 (22621.2506) is launching Windows Terminal with a Powershell tab open, the font name is "Cascadia Mono" and size 12. I don't even know if it's possible to open the old blue Powershell window on this version of Windows, that particular "console host" seems to be dead and buried in newer Windows 11 versions.

@Romen - You just switch the default terminal from Windows Terminal to Windows Console Host

I can confirm the default PowerShell 5.1 and PowerShell 7 font is indeed Consolas size 16 on Windows 11 23H2. Since I know the configuration for PowerShell 5.1 has not changed in over 5 years, if I were to hazard to guess, the default on Windows 10 is the same.  As for the difference between size 14 and size 16 you likely changed it.

This is actually, unfortunately, an impossible to answer question. It's not powershell that determines the font. It's the terminal application that powershell is running within. Basically, powershell is the prompt and the commands that can be run from that prompt... but the window, colors, and font are all part of the terminal.
On Windows 11 powershell (and cmd) uses the new "Windows Terminal" application and, on my system at least, that defaults to Cascadia Mono. I believe most versions of Windows 10 also have Windows Terminal but I seem to recall powershell opening in a different terminal app by default... tempted to say it used Windows Console. Speaking of... there's the venerable "Windows Console" that was available from Windows 9x/NT to Windows 10 and was used for the cmd prompt. I've no idea what the default font on those were or whether it remained the same for that entire time. There are also a number of third party terminals that can be installed on Windows and used with cmd, powershell, or even sh/bash/zsh/fish/openssh/whatever... for example MSYS, mobaxterm, etc. All of those will also each have different default fonts.

This question can be answered without an issue. A PowerShell console (not a Windows Terminal console) can still be launched on Windows 11.

There's no such thing as a "powershell console". On Windows 11 attempting to run powershell opens the Windows Terminal app with powershell as the interpreter.

I disagree.  Windows PowerShell launches a console application. It only launches Windows Terminal if you don't modify the default terminal handler to be Windows Console Host from Windows Terminal. On Windows 10, it cannot be changed to Windows Terminal since the default console handler cannot be changed.  You can change the default shell from PowerShell to Command Prompt on Windows 10 (and Windows Terminal).  PowerShell was changed to the default on Windows 10 more than 5 years ago.

That's still not "powershell console" That's the old Windows Console. The same one that's been used as the terminal app for cmd since Windows NT. As I stated in my answer above.

There is a difference between the console PowerShell application and PowerShell ISE. It is still possible to launch PowerShell (not Windows Terminal) on all versions of Windows 11.   When I use the term "PowerShell console" I refer to the (x86 or x64) console application.  On Windows 10, PowerShell is the default Windows Console Host handler.

Powershell ISE has not at any point been part of this conversation. As I explained in my answer above there are two categories of applications being discussed. The interpreter (either powershell or cmd) and the terminal (either Windows Terminal or, as you call it, Windows Console Host). The terminal application is what determines the font, not the interpreter. Yes, Powershell ISE has a terminal built into it... much like MS Code does... but those are more development environments than pure terminal applications. Powershell ISE is not powershell... it is a dev env for crafting ps scripts.

It actually was. It was in the deleted answer. But it doesn’t matter I was using it only to separate the (x86 x64) PowerShell 5.1 console application from PowerShell ISE. I am well aware what PowerShell ISE is by the way. As I call it…. Do you realize I got Windows Console Host directly from Microsoft Windows Terminal? I get you believe I don’t know what I am talking about but I promise you I actually do, you don’t need to talk down to me, or explain something as basic as what PowerShell ISE actually is. I am just going to leave. I’ll submit my answer shortly


I am fairly new to PowerShell. The font Consolas size 16 has been the default in the PowerShell console, on the machine on which I started learning PowerShell, which runs Windows 11 22H2 (22621.674).

Consolas is the default font for PowerShell 5.1+ running within a Windows Host Console on both Windows 10 22H2 and all versions of Windows 11.

I recently had to use PowerShell on another machine and the default font was Lucida Console, however in the same size 16. That machine runs Windows 10 22H2 (19045.5131) and was freshly re-imaged, however not by me (company laptop).

The font assigned to PowerShell is on a per user basis, to my knowledge, while possible to change the font and font size for the default user and thus all future users it cannot be configured where the font cannot be changed. In other words either the Administrator responsible for creating the Windows image or you as the user changed the font and font size from Consolas.

My personal machine is on W10 22H2 and has Consolas, however in size 14, as the default.


What font and size is set by default for PowerShell console on fresh installs of Windows?

I created 3 VMs to verify this answer in all three the default font and font size was the same, Consolas size 16. I create a Windows 10 22H2, Windows 11 23H2, and Windows 11 24H2 VM.
